# How do I split a cell in Excel into two or more where they are divided horizontally?

Tags: excel

How do I split a cell in Excel into two or more where they are divided horizontally. Please see the screenshot below:

You'll notice that row number 2 (cat/parrot) is divided. I'm not sure how to replicate this.
I tried CMD + ALT + Enter which split the text on two lines, but that is not the effect I'm looking for. In the screenshot example the cat and parrot are selectable like they are in their own cells.

thanks for any help
[image]

Comment: I think A3 and A4 are probably merged (as with columns C, D, E, F)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cell you are looking at is not divided but the cells to the right are 'merge &  centered'  there is a button for that in the ribbon at the top of your window under the home tab

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you cannot split an individual cell. What you can do is highlight the entire row and insert a new row. From there, merge each indiv. cell back together except for the cell you wanted divided. This will make it appear as if the individual cell is split.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't allow you to click the lines as separately selectable data, but if wanted to just have 2 clean lines within one cell:
Click the cell, enter the first line of data, then **Alt + Enter** to go to the next line within the same cell.